# Different views for horizontal and vertical when phone is rotated

Tags: android

How I can i set different views for horizontal and vertical displays when phone is rotated?

Answer (score 4):

You can describe different layouts for portrait and landscape orientation. You should place layout for portrait mode into `res/layout-port`, and for landscape into `res/layout-land`

Read more at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html, **Providing Alternative Resources** section

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing the Application for your own then use wrap_content and fill_parent size in height and width. Becouse if you are given any static value then it will effect on the Layout of your phone size. as there are different sizes of phone available for android in the Market.
Thanks.

Comment: You can also Fix the Size of your application by adding the orientation to the manifest file.. as like :   android:screenOrientation="portrait"